Не могу завершить стейт в aiogram 3 Прошу помочь
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.filters import Command, StateFilter
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import Message
@router.message(RegAnceta.register_age, F.text)
async def surname_reg(message: Message):
    age = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Ваша анкета -  {name} {surname} {age}./n Если хотите её изменить, то напишите /deleteanceta, а затем снова напишите /Anceta")
    await state.clear()
    flag = True

Выдает ошибку - Unresolved reference 'state' на строчке await state.clear
Подключенные библиотеки. Если что, это не главный файл

Потому что в аргументах функции этот самый стейт надо прописывать:
@router.message(RegAnceta.register_age, F.text)
async def surname_reg(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    ...

